# Received status code 408 from server: Request Timeout, even after the server is up

Tags: eclipse, gradle, build, server, repository

I am not able to found out the issue. I am getting the below, when I am running gradle build for my project:

`"http://stlprdbnd01:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/xyz/app/system/SIAL-CDI/CONFIG-0.0.6/SIAL-CDI-CONFIG-0.0.6.pom- Received status code 408 from server: Request Timeout"`

I tried the repository url using browser. It is up and running. I am able to download the jar also. But using build command I am getting the above issue.

Same issue exists when I tried to refresh dependencies using eclipse also.

I dont know where I went wrong. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue. Problem was with my proxy. I was using some wrong proxy server. I removed it. It worked and I was able to download jar from remote repository